# Cannot convert value of type 'HorarioData?.Type' to expected argument type 'HorarioData?'

Tags: api, swift, swift2, swift3, swift4

Estoy trabajando con una API local, ya definí la estructura para recibir mi API.

```
struct  AppointmentsList: Decodable {
    let data: [appoint]?
    let horarioData: HorarioData?
    let msg: String?
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct appoint: Decodable {
    let v, folio: Int?
    let cliente, mascota, dia, hora: String?
    let id, creado, estatus, tipo: String?
    let empleado: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case v = "__v"
        case folio, cliente, mascota, dia, hora
        case id = "_id"
        case creado, estatus, tipo, empleado
    }
}

// MARK: - HorarioData
struct HorarioData: Decodable {
    let n, nModified, ok: Int?
}
```

El problema radica en que cuando quiero crear una variable para llamar a la estructura AppointmentList, me marca un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo entendido es que horarioData recibe al objeto HorarioData? pero no sé como llamarlo correctamente.

**¿Cuál es mi error?**

Comment: Es `HorarioData.self`

Comment: No, no me funcionó.

Comment: Intentaste las estructuras con Codable?

Comment: Ya, no funciona de igual forma. Me marca el mismo error.

Comment: Para pasar como parámetro debes primero crear el objeto de tipo `HorarioData`.